# Stripe paymentIntent vs Subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

Following a guide for my server (**Firebase**) they charge the user with :

```
const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
    {
      amount,
      currency,
      customer,
      payment_method,
      off_session: false,
      confirm: true,
      confirmation_method: 'manual',
    },
    { idempotencyKey }
  );
```

Now in all **Stripe** examples, they use something like:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
  items: [{
    price: '{{RECURRING_PRICE_ID}}',
  }],
  add_invoice_items: [{
    price: '{{PRICE_ID}}',
  }],
});
```

I am trying to understand :

1. What this `paymentIntent` does ? and how it relate to a subscription ? ( for me it just charge the user and its not clear if this is one time charge or a subscription )
2. Where is the Product that I created in the dashboard fits here ? I have a *subscription product* on the Dashboard , i would like to subscribe to that product ID, and not set a new price.

Reading the docs doesn't help since it is full of so much information and options without a clean flow.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A PaymentIntent is an object used to collect payment one time. A Subscription is a higher level concept that represents a relationship between a Customer and some recurring Price they will pay on an interval.

When a Subscription renews, there is an Invoice generated which will use an underlying PaymentIntent to collect money for that renewal.

When you create a Product in the dashboard, it will have one or more Prices. A Product would be something like "Starter" or "Pro" and the Prices related to each Product represent the currency (USD), amount to charge (1000) and some interval at which the Price should recur at if any. Note: Prices can also be used for one time purchases with Checkout.

In this video about the new Customer portal, we cover modeling your business with Prices and it might be helpful here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8H6awDJVpM&list=PLy1nL-pvL2M6IYfRCmhOPcyC70zJqFoCs&index=2&t=0s

We need to create a subscription not a payment intent. When the subscription is created we get the client_secret for initiating the payment process:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but i could already understand what you explained from the docs. What i don't understand is the syntax difference, and when do you use each one of them. For example, in the first attempt to charge AND start the subscription, which one is used?

Comment: To start the subscription and charge, you just create the Subscription.

Comment: i am not sure it is true, you need to create a payment intent, and actually nothing is clear about it.

Comment: You do not need to directly create a payment intent when creating a subscription.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out all this mess too. I am creating a subscription on the server. it looks like it comes with its own paymentIntent so I stopped creating a separate paymentIntent with own id, which didn't work for completing the subscription. The subscription's paymentIntent has a confirmation_method set as automatic. But it results in an error after SCA on the frontend: "You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has already succeeded after being previously confirmed". I am totally confused how to make subscription/PI work with SCA. @cjav_dev and any other Stripe devs, pls help!!!

Comment: Yes, I think Stripe have done a bad job here. If you want to support SCA you'll need to create an intent (you should probably specify "off_session: true" in the intent too), and then use stripe.confirmCardPayment() on the frontend. This will handle any SCA requirements, but it will also give you a result.paymentIntent.payment_method value you can use to create a sub. Be warned, if you create a Subscription immediately you'll take a second payment straight away too. You could perhaps use the trial_end value when creating the subscription, to give your users credit from that first payment.

Comment: @Vlad - i had the same issue, hope you have sorted the subscription issue now, anyway who ever is looking for an answer on this here I the reference - https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements. We need to create a subscription not an payment intent, when the subscription is created we are able to get the client_secret for the first time form to submit.